# access-control-allow-origin on playframework

Tags: playframework, same-origin-policy

How can I get playframework to allow non-origin calls? I have tried adding a @Before method to a controller, but that never gets called by an ajax client.

```
@Before 
public static void setCORS()
{
    Http.Response.current().accessControl("*", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE", true);
}
```

I am trying to setup a test API server for client developers to test against, but that seems to require disabling the Origin restriction.

Has anyone else got this working? or accomplished this in a different way?

**UPDATE:**
I found this article on the topic 
http://javathought.wordpress.com/2011/12/04/cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-play-framework/

Comment: Are you trying to call play-project from a different domain or the other way around?

Comment: I am trying to call play from another domain. Specificly, I am setting up a test play on a hosted server and a web client being developed on a local desktop. I am trying to setup a development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what your browser is trying to do, it may send an OPTION request first to check what is allowed, this is called "preflight request".

Also, setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * only works without credentials.

Comment: This is a good page to read through, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

Comment: Thank you nylund. Is there a way to get Play to put these headers on every call? The options check is coming back as a 404, likely because the GET, PUT, POST, DELETE calls are routed but not the OPTIONS verb.

Comment: You have to add an OPTION route to your routes.conf file, you could use wildcards to cover as much as you like if it makes sense in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom router can solve this.

For example using: https://github.com/teamon/play-navigator

```
val rget = GET on "foo" to App.foo
val gpost = POST on "foo" to App.foo
```